# Android data-binding library not working with latest Gradle versions

Tags: android, android-studio, data-binding, gradle

The Android data-binding library does not work with the latest Gradle betas (1.4.0-beta2 to beta6). I have previously successfully used Gradle 1.4.0-beta1, however starting today, Gradle throws the following error message:

> Error:(1, 0) Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent
>   version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to
>   "82c9bc6593d7d8c9f099ef879af7ec51940f8b4b"

Is there any combination of gradle/data-binding that still works without setting the ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable? If not, where should I set this environment variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.0-rc3 was just released. It will work with 1.4-beta5.

Answer (score 1):

Gradle version 1.3.1 works with data-binding library version 1.0-rc2.

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc2"
```

However, this still means that I cannot use Gradle-1.4.0 features such as Vector images.